# How do I switch between fragments using the ExpandableBottomBar menu items?

Tags: android, kotlin, github, fragment, bottomnavigationview

The app starts normal with no fragment and when I click on any of the items in the bottom menu bar the app crashes suddenly. I have used the [ExpandableBottomBar github repository](https://github.com/st235/ExpandableBottomBar) to create this bottom bar menu. If you need any more info I will provide. I need help as this is my first app. Thanks!

Here is the Logcat file:

```
2022-01-07 15:02:13.652 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:93195): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.psmforums.skillyourself/code_cache/startup_agents/a67b7118-agent.so" dev="dm-10" ino=71765 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c107,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c107,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.psmforums.skillyourself
        dev_cert_hash: -8472035670327217949
        app_store: manual_install
2022-01-07 15:02:13.657 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/s.skillyoursel: DexFile /data/data/com.psmforums.skillyourself/code_cache/.studio/instruments-3e620333.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
2022-01-07 15:02:13.665 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/s.skillyoursel: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
2022-01-07 15:02:13.657 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself V/studio.deploy: No existing instrumentation found. Loading instrumentation from instruments-3e620333.jar
        app_instance_id: 92c2e9455736943c0e772cf0035ab296
        resettable_device_id: fd0d8f22-9ef2-44a6-b7cb-cebbf2cf7346
        ds_id: DSID=AAO-7r5_MpYPzTjAgaC32wDQfkvSzginNg07mmfRIc5rdOjYKQfDMPKbW2npGj0Hsmw-UyiHngI5VghRAR5MZipfG_n7_lhRNKSSV_awotneUkGSDqMFFe8
        limited_ad_tracking: false
        os_version: 12
2022-01-07 15:02:13.665 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/s.skillyoursel: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
        device_model: Pixel 6 Pro
        user_default_language: en-in
        time_zone_offset_minutes: 330
        bundle_sequential_index: 78
2022-01-07 15:02:13.668 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10363; state: ENABLED
        service_upload: true
        health_monitor: 
        consent_signals: G1--
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1641321205507
          name: first_open_time(_fot)
          string_value: 
          int_value: 1641322800000
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1641321205507
          name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
          string_value: 
          int_value: 1
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1641547572273
          name: ga_session_number(_sno)
          string_value: 
          int_value: 13
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1641547572273
          name: ga_session_id(_sid)
          string_value: 
          int_value: 1641547572
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1641547933001
          name: lifetime_user_engagement(_lte)
          string_value: 
          int_value: 2988248
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1641547933001
          name: session_user_engagement(_se)
          string_value: 
          int_value: 10722
        }
        event {
          name: screen_view(_vs)
          timestamp_millis: 1641547928632
          previous_timestamp_millis: 1641547585012
          param {
            name: ga_event_origin(_o)
            string_value: auto
          }
          param {
            name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
            string_value: MainActivity
          }
          param {
            name: ga_screen_id(_si)
            int_value: -253887690339264981
          }
        }
        event {
          name: app_exception(_ae)
          timestamp_millis: 1641547932362
          previous_timestamp_millis: 1641547587265
          param {
            name: ga_event_origin(_o)
            string_value: clx
          }
          param {
            name: _r
            int_value: 1
          }
          param {
            name: engagement_time_msec(_et)
            int_value: 3830
          }
          param {
            name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
            string_value: MainActivity
          }
          param {
            name: ga_screen_id(_si)
            int_value: -253887690339264981
          }
          param {
            name: timestamp
            int_value: 1641547931749
          }
          param {
            name: fatal
            int_value: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
2022-01-07 15:02:13.613 6041-6041/? I/s.skillyoursel: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-01-07 15:02:13.632 6041-6041/? D/ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
2022-01-07 15:02:13.652 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:93195): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/com.psmforums.skillyourself/code_cache/startup_agents/a67b7118-agent.so" dev="dm-10" ino=71765 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c107,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c107,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.psmforums.skillyourself
2022-01-07 15:02:13.657 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/s.skillyoursel: DexFile /data/data/com.psmforums.skillyourself/code_cache/.studio/instruments-3e620333.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
2022-01-07 15:02:13.665 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/s.skillyoursel: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
2022-01-07 15:02:13.665 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself W/s.skillyoursel: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
2022-01-07 15:02:13.668 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10363; state: ENABLED
2022-01-07 15:02:13.887 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-01-07 15:02:13.887 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-01-07 15:02:13.888 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 1531297613045645771; UID 10363; state: DISABLED
2022-01-07 15:02:13.888 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 7528921493777479941; UID 10363; state: DISABLED
2022-01-07 15:02:13.917 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2022-01-07 15:02:13.952 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.2.6 for com.psmforums.skillyourself
2022-01-07 15:02:13.966 6041-6071/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:55 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:59
2022-01-07 15:02:13.966 6041-6071/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 59
2022-01-07 15:02:13.991 6041-6082/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
2022-01-07 15:02:14.012 6041-6041/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2022-01-07 15:02:14.026 6041-6084/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lDY2traUg4aTJaQVJ3T3MxTEV6RktsZDE1YU9HOG96S28=) is already scheduled. Returning...
2022-01-07 15:02:14.027 6041-6084/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, HIGHEST, MSRodHRwczovL2NyYXNobHl0aWNzcmVwb3J0cy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lCcnBTWVQ0RkZMMDlyZUhKaTZIOUZZZGVpU25VVE92Mk0=) is already scheduled. Returning...
2022-01-07 15:02:14.096 6041-6084/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Making request to: https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog
2022-01-07 15:02:14.114 6041-6087/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 50018
2022-01-07 15:02:14.114 6041-6087/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2022-01-07 15:02:14.114 6041-6087/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.psmforums.skillyourself
2022-01-07 15:02:14.114 6041-6087/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2022-01-07 15:02:14.213 6041-6087/com.psmforums.skillyourself D/FA: Connected to remote service
2022-01-07 15:02:16.337 6041-6084/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Status Code: 200
2022-01-07 15:02:16.337 6041-6084/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2022-01-07 15:02:16.337 6041-6084/com.psmforums.skillyourself I/TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Here is my MainAcivity.kt file:

```
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
import com.google.firebase.analytics.ktx.analytics
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.psmforums.skillyourself.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import github.com.st235.lib_expandablebottombar.ExpandableBottomBar
import github.com.st235.lib_expandablebottombar.MenuItemDescriptor
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics

        val bottomBar: ExpandableBottomBar = findViewById(R.id.expandable_bottom_bar)
        val menu = bottomBar.menu

        menu.add(
            MenuItemDescriptor.Builder(this,
                R.id.home,
                R.drawable.ic_home_foreground,
                R.string.homeBtn,
                Color.GREEN)
                .build()
        )

        menu.add(
            MenuItemDescriptor.Builder
                (this,R.id.search,
                R.drawable.ic_search_foreground,
                R.string.searchBtn,
                Color.YELLOW)
                .build()
        )

        menu.add(
            MenuItemDescriptor.Builder(this,
                R.id.profile,
                R.drawable.ic_profile,
                R.string.profileBtn,
                Color.MAGENTA)
                .build()
        )

        menu.add(
            MenuItemDescriptor.Builder(this,
                R.id.settings,
                R.drawable.ic_settings_foreground,
                R.string.settingsBtn,
                Color.RED)
                .build()
        )

        bottomBar.onItemSelectedListener = { view, menuItem, Boolean ->
            when(menuItem.id){
                R.id.home ->
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.layout, HomePage())
                        .commit()
                R.id.search ->
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.layout, SearchPage())
                        .commit()
                R.id.profile ->
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.layout, ProfilePage())
                        .commit()
                R.id.settings ->
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.layout, SettingsPage())
                        .commit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide crash logcat?

Comment: Sure I'll add it in the question only!

Comment: @PuranjaySavarMattas are you still struggling with this? I believe your logcat file does not capture the actual crash.

Comment: Nope I solved it I don't remember now how, but I will update it with a solution